# BitmapImage or ImageStream to image file - Windows 10

Tags: c#, image, win-universal-app

I have [Windows.Graphics.Imaging ImageStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.graphics.imaging.imagestream.aspx). It is easy to get it as source of XAML Image:

```
BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
bitmapImage.SetSource(imageStream);

XAMLImage.Source = bitmapImage;
```

But I did not figured out how to save it to image file (png,jpg,...) in Windows 10 app.

Thnx for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not save a BitmapImage as png or jepg file, you should use WriteableBitmap to instead.

CODE(How to save a WriteableBitmap as JPEG):

```
    var image = new WriteableBitmap(50, 50);

    var file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/StoreLogo.png"));

    var content = await file.OpenReadAsync();

    image.SetSource(content);

    var saveAsTarget = await KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary.CreateFileAsync("saveas.jpg");

    BitmapEncoder encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(
        BitmapEncoder.JpegEncoderId, 
        await saveAsTarget.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite));

    Stream pixelStream = image.PixelBuffer.AsStream();

    byte[] pixels = new byte[pixelStream.Length];

    await pixelStream.ReadAsync(pixels, 0, pixels.Length);

    encoder.SetPixelData(BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, BitmapAlphaMode.Ignore, (uint)image.PixelWidth, (uint)image.PixelHeight, 96.0, 96.0, pixels);

    await encoder.FlushAsync();
```

Comment: you can set a file stream as the image srouce by call SetSource method of BitmapImage

Comment: for your case, you can replace the file stream by using the image stream

Comment: Thnx. It works, but there is problem with opening file, while my app si running (it locks the file)... This is the solution:  using (var writeStream = await saveAsTarget.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite)) (line before BitmapEncoder)